# Error when calling gridview.Columns.RemoveAt in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am getting an error: **Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index**  when my code gvGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(0) is executed below. What am missing here ?

```
gvGrid.DataSource = eCustomerMgr.GetCustHistory(oCust);
gvGrid.DataBind();  
gvGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```

The code block is being used to export data to excel.

**Update:** Using @Lajos Arpad suggestion, this is what I see:

[image]

however, when I hover over gvGrid.Columns.Count, I get 0

[image]

Why is the grid count showing 0 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why the Columns.Count is showing 0, but if you are interested in an alternative, maybe you can try `gvGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;` where 0 is the column # that you are looking to remove. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First bind and then remove or remove column for data source before you bind

```
gvGrid.DataSource = eCustomerMgr.GetCustHistory(oCust);
gvGrid.DataBind();  
gvGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
```

Remove column before you bind it to grid, suppose you have datatable

```
   DataTable t;
   t.Columns.Remove("columnName");
   t.Columns.RemoveAt(columnIndex);
```

Comment: assign the eCustomerMgr.GetCustHistory(oCust) to some data table and check if you get the data or the empty data table with just column name like DataTable dt = eCustomerMgr.GetCustHistory(oCust); Get columns of dt like dt.Columns.Count to make sure you are getting columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
gvGrid.DataSource = eCustomerMgr.GetCustHistory(oCust);
gvGrid.DataBind();  
if (gvGrid.Columns.Count > 0)
{
    gvGrid.Columns.RemoveAt(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about data, then first DataBind then RemoveAt.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that `eCustomerMgr.GetCustHistory(oCust);` is returning data and bind grid before removing column..

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that you have done the  `AutoGenerateColumns="False"` and defined the columnns name.

If you want to remove column dynamically you have to predefined the columns name.
as ex.

```
  <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" />
        </Columns>
```

Now when you remove the column zero, It will remove the column.

Comment: @DotNetRookie definitely your grid have autogeneratecolumn property is true and you are binding whole date which is available in the viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (gvGrid.Rows.Count > 0) {

  gvGrid.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Visible = false;

  for (int i = 0; i < gvGrid.Rows.Count; i++) {
   gvGrid.Rows[i].Cells[0].Visible = false;

  }
 }
```

Comment: Could you expand on why this is the solution and how it works?